# Average place within a group in a competition with equal skill

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

> ${43}$ equally strong sportsmen take part in a ski race; 18 of
> them belong to club ${A}$, 10 to club  and 15 to club ${C}$. What is the
> average place for (a) the best participant from club ${B}$; (b) the
> worst participant from club ${B}$?

---

I've found the possible range of places the participant could get for both cases. In the case (a), the best participant from club ${B}$ can be at any place between $1$ and $34$. As for the case (b), the worst participant from club $B$ can get any place between $10$ and $43$. To find the average place I need to compute the expected (mean) value of the this variable. But I'm not sure how to find the chances for getting each place. I suppose they should be equal, but neither $\frac{1}{33}$ nor $\frac{1}{43}$ seem to give the right answer.

Comment: As I said, I accept the analysis that you posted in a comment following the answer of Mike Earnest.  However, I am still unsure about the validity of Mike Earnest's analysis.  See also [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243655/validating-probability-theory-analysis-about-average-place-in-a-group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding the probability of each place and doing $\sum k\,p(k)$, you can use this trick.

When all the people are lined up in order of place, the ten people in the $B$ group will divide the line into $11$ contiguous sections. These sections are composed of the $43-10=33$ people from groups $A$ and $C$. Furthermore, each person in $A\cup C$ is equally likely to be in any of these $11$ spots. It follows that the expected number of $A\cup C$ members in each section is $33/11=3$. Using this, you should be able to deduce the average positions of the best from the $B$ club and the worst from the $B$ club.

Here is an illustrative picture. $B_1$ is the best, $B_{10}$ is the worst.
$$
\newcommand{\s}{\,\boxed{\,\;3\;\,}\,}
\s B_1
\s B_2
\s B_3
\s B_4
\s B_5
\s B_6
\s B_7
\s B_8
\s B_9
\s B_{10} 
\s
$$

---

Why is each of the gaps equally likely? Let $X$ be a particular person in clubs $A$ or $C$. We will group all of the orderings into sets of $11$, where $X$ is in a different gap in each set. Therefore, the fraction of orderings where $X$ is in any particular gap is $1/11$.

In each set, all of the people except for the $B$ club and $X$ will retain their positions, while $X$ will swap with some of the $B$ members as follows. Each $\cdots$ obscures a sequence of $A$ and $C$ members is the same for all $11$ orderings.
$$
\#1) \cdots X\cdots B_1\cdots B_2\cdots B_3\cdots B_4 \cdots B_5\cdots B_6\cdots B_7\cdots B_8\cdots B_9\cdots B_{10}\cdots\\\,\\
\#2)\cdots B_1\cdots X\cdots B_2\cdots B_3\cdots B_4 \cdots B_5\cdots B_6\cdots B_7\cdots B_8\cdots B_9\cdots B_{10}\cdots\\\,\\
\#3)\cdots B_1\cdots B_2\cdots X\cdots B_3\cdots B_4 \cdots B_5\cdots B_6\cdots B_7\cdots B_8\cdots B_9\cdots B_{10}\cdots\\\,\\
\vdots\\\,\\
\#11)\cdots B_1\cdots B_2\cdots B_3\cdots B_4 \cdots B_5\cdots B_6\cdots B_7\cdots B_8\cdots B_9\cdots B_{10}\cdots X\cdots
$$

Comment: Can you explain why it’s equally likely for each person from $A \cup B$ to be in any piece of the partition? That doesn’t seem obvious to me.

Comment: I question this approach.  In my answer, I regard average position to be $\sum_{k=1}^{34} \left[k \times p(k)\right]$, where $p(k) = ~$ the probability that the highest ranking member of B is in position $k$.  So the first question that I have is: *have* *I* *misinterpreted* *the* *problem*?  If not, then it seems that a *higher* *weight* must be given to those events where the leading person in B is in a numerically higher position.  I would be very surprised if my math agreed with the average position being position #4.  Assuming that my math disagrees, can you find a mistake in my answer?

Comment: @user2661923 Prepare to be very surprised! [Wolfram|Alpha computation proving your answer equals 4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%2F43+%2B+sum+k*33%21%2F%2834-k%29%21*%2844-k%29%21%2F43%21*10%2F%2844-k%29+from+k+%3D+2+to+34).

Comment: Oh, thats really smart! But its also not entirely clear for me why each person from $A \cup C$ is equally likely to be in any of these 11 spots.

Comment: @RainCatalyst I added an explanation. Think about it like this; if you shuffle a deck of cards, the 13 hearts will divide the deck into 14 sections. Which section is most likely for the ace of spades? It turns out each section is equally likely, since the section for $A\spadesuit$ is determined by relative ordering of those 14 cards alone (the 14 hearts and the $A\spadesuit$), and all $14!$ of those relative orderings are equally likely, so there is no bias for $A\spadesuit$'s position in that ordering.

Comment: Define an indicator variable $x_i = \{1 : \text{if i'th player has a better result than everyone from group B}, 0: \text{otherwise}\}$. Then $X = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{33}{x_i}$ is a total number of players better than everyone from $B$. The chance that $x_i = 1$ is $\frac{1}{11}$ (suppose you only got 11 people, 10 from group $B$ and one person is anyone from groups $A$ and $C$, so the chance that this person is higher than anyone from $B$ is 1/11). The expected value of $X$ is $33 * \frac{1}{11} = 3$. So the average place for the best person from $B$ is 4 (because there are 3 people above).

Comment: @RainCatalyst Believe it or not, I actually understand your last comment.  It makes a lot of sense to me.  There is the unspoken foundation that [linearity of expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) holds for dependent events.  I suggest that you post the analysis in your comment directly into your posted question.

Comment: To Mike Earnest: For what it's worth, the only reason that I don't upvote your answer is that I lack the intuition-sophistication to know that your answer is valid.  I don't think that the Wolfram Alpha verification is coincidental, and I do understand that linearity of expectation holds for dependent events.  But still, this one is hard for me to wrap my brain around.

Comment: To Mike Earnest: I understand your $A\spadesuit$ logic, and the logic in your answer.  So let's assume that the expected gap before the 1st B member, and after each of the B members is 3 slots.  Based on this assumption, how do you analytically show that $4 = \sum kp(k)$?  For example, there is some chance that the gap before the 1st B member might be $2$, or $4$, rather than $3$.  These events do not balance each other, because the 1st event must be given a weight of $(2 + 1)$, and the 2nd event must be given a weight of $(4 + 1)$.  This is where I become uncertain about your approach.

Comment: @user2661923 These comment boxes are too small to explain clearly. Why not post a separate question?

Comment: To Mike Earnest : done - see [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243655/validating-probability-theory-analysis-about-average-place-in-a-group).

Answer (score 1):

First see the answer of Mike Earnest, and the comments following his answer.  Apparently, my computation numerically agrees with his answer.

---

Alternative approach:

$\underline{\text{Problem 1:}}$

For $k \in \{1,2,\cdots,34\},~$ let
$p(k)$ denote the probability that the highest member of B is in position $k$.

Then, the expected position for the highest member of $B$ will be $$\sum_{k=1}^{34} \left[k \times p(k)\right].$$

Therefore, the problem reduces to computing $p(k)$.

For $k$ to be the highest position of any member of B, two things have to happen:

- Positions $1,2,\cdots,(k-1)$ must be taken by someone in either A or C.  If $k$ = 1, we can denote this event as having probability $= 1.$  For $k > 1$ then the probability of this happening is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{33!}{[33 - (k-1)]!} \times \frac{[43 - (k-1)]!}{43!} = \frac{33!}{(34 - k)!} \times \frac{(44 - k)!}{43!}.$
- Position $k$ must be taken by someone in B, **after** all of the previous positions have been taken by someone in either A or C.  The probability of this happening is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{10}{44 - k}.$

Therefore, the expected value of the position of the highest ranking member of B is

$$\left\{1 \times \frac{10}{43}\right\} ~+~
\left\{ ~\sum_{k=2}^{34} \left[k \times 
\frac{33!}{(34 - k)!} \times \frac{(44 - k)!}{43!} \times \frac{10}{44 - k}\right]
~\right\}.
$$

---

$\underline{\text{Problem 2:}}$

Since most of the groundwork has already been done in Problem 1, the easiest approach for Problem 2 is to consider it to be the **mirror** problem to Problem 1.  That is, the math is all exactly the same, but for each event that would be multiplied by the scalar $k$, you instead multiply it by the scalar $(44 - k)$.

Therefore, there is no need to repeat the analysis from Problem 1.  The expected value of the position of the lowest ranking member of B is

$$\left\{43 \times \frac{10}{43}\right\} ~+~
\left\{ ~\sum_{k=2}^{34} \left[(44 - k) \times 
\frac{33!}{(34 - k)!} \times \frac{(44 - k)!}{43!} \times \frac{10}{44 - k}\right]
~\right\}.
$$

Comment: Your solution looks reasonable. After going through both yours and Mike Earnest's solutions, it seems that your probability function looks specifically for the highest member of B, so it is position dependent. While Mike Earnest looks at the probability of a person from $A \cup C$ being in an arbitrary place after the Bs' places are distributed, so it doesn't depend on position.

Comment: @RainCatalyst Did you notice the Wolfram Alpha link that Mike Earnest placed in a comment, following his answer?  It verified that my computation agrees with his.  I was very surprised by this.

Answer (score 0):

The position of the highest placed person from $B$ (call this $X$) can be anywhere from $1$ to $34$, but these are not equally likely. For $X=1$ you simply need person $1$ to be from club $B$. This has probability $18/43$. For $X=10$, say, you need person $10$ to be from club $B$ (probability $18/43$) **and** none of the previous $9$ people to be from $B$. So you need the remaining $17$ members of $B$ (who can be in any $17$ of the remaining $42$ positions) all to be within the last $33$. This has probability $\frac{\binom{33}{9}}{\binom{42}{9}}$, so overall you get
$$\Pr(X=10)=\frac{18}{43}\times\frac{\binom{33}{9}}{\binom{42}{9}}.$$