# Validating Probability Theory analysis about average place in a group

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

**Overview** 
In this posting I present a recent mathSE question.  In the recent question, there
were (in effect) three different approaches taken to answer the question.  All
three approaches reached the same conclusion.  I understood two of the approaches,
but not the third.

In this posting, I am going to discuss the original question as well as the
three approaches.

**My question is** 
Why is the third approach valid?

---

**The Original Question** 
The question was originally posted
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243344/average-place-within-a-group-in-a-competition-with-equal-skill/4243382).

The question is

> $43$  equally strong sportsmen take part in a ski race; $18$ of them belong to club A,
> $10$ to club B and $15$ to club C. What is the average place for the best participant
> from club B?

You will notice that I omitted the 2nd half of the original question as not being
relevant to the issue that I wish to discuss.

---

**My Background**
50 years ago, as a Math major, I took a Probability course.  I understood it at
the time.  Now, I rely almost exclusively on intuition to attack Probability
problems.  I have been able to understand the proof of Linearity of Expectation
with respect to dependent events, as proven in
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).

---

**The First Approach** 
Especially Lime and I each posted a separate answer to the original question.  Both of our answers (in effect) used the
same computational approach.  The idea was that the best person from B might
occupy any of positions $(1)$ through $(34)$.  Therefore, the expected position
can be computed as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{34} \left[k \times p(k)\right]$$

where $p(k)$ is the probability that the best person from B occupied place $(k)$.

The computation that I gave was:

$$\left\{1 \times \frac{10}{43}\right\} ~+~
\left\{ ~\sum_{k=2}^{34} \left[k \times 
\frac{33!}{(34 - k)!} \times \frac{(44 - k)!}{43!} \times \frac{10}{44 - k}\right]
~\right\}.
$$

[This Wolfram Alpha Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%2F43+%2B+sum+k%2A33%21%2F%2834-k%29%21%2A%2844-k%29%21%2F43%21%2A10%2F%2844-k%29+from+k+%3D+2+to+34)
indicates that the above summation results in an answer of $(4)$.

---

**The Second Approach** 
In a comment following the answer of Especially Lime, in the original question, the original poster (i.e. the OP)
of the original question, RainCatalyst, posted the following analysis:

Consider the $33$ people who are not in B.  For $i \in \{1,2,\cdots,33\}$, let
$x_i$ denote an indicator variable assigned to one of the people that is not in B.

Define the value of $x_i$ as follows:

- $x_i = 1 ~: ~$ if the $i$-th player has a better result than everyone from group B
- $x_i = 0 ~: ~$ otherwise.

Then $\displaystyle \left\{ ~X = \sum_{i=1}^{33} x_i ~\right\}~$ represents the total number of players better
than everyone from B. If you consider any random person not in B, along with the
$(10)$ people in B, you have a group of $(11)$ people, anyone of whom is equally likely
to have the highest position.  Therefore, for each variable $x_i$, the probability
that $x_i$ = $(1)$, rather than $(0)$ is $\frac{1}{11}.$

Therefore, the expected value of $X$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{33} \left[\frac{1}{11}\right].$ 
Since the expected value of $X$ is $(3)$, the expected value of the
person in B who finished the highest is therefore $(4)$.  This is because you expect that there are
$(3)$ people from A or C that finished ahead of the best person from B.

I understand this analysis, which depends on Linearity of Expectation, and it does make sense to me.

---

**The Third Approach**
This is the one that I have trouble with.  It comes from Mike Earnest's answer to the original question. 
I will try to paraphrase his thinking.  However, it is probably best if you examine
his answer directly, as well as his comments following his answer.

> His approach (in effect) is to label the people in B as $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{10}$,
> where $b_1$ finished the best, and $b_{10}$ finished the worst.  Then, there are
> $11$ **positional gaps** created: before $b_1$, and after each of $b_1$ through $b_{10}$.

> Each of the $(33)$ people that are not in B are equally likely to be positioned in any of
> the $(11)$ postional gaps.  Therefore, you would expect each positional gap to contain (on average) $(3)$ people
> who are not in B.  Under this presumption, you expect that the first positional gap contains $(3)$ people who
> are not in B.  Therefore, the best person from B is expected to finish in position $(4)$.

I certainly don't regard it as coincidental that his answer matches the first two approaches.  However, I
have trouble understanding why his analysis leads to the right answer.

Simply because the most likely distribution of the 33 people in the 11 positional gaps is 
$3 - 3 - 3 - \cdots - 3$, does not imply that other distributions can not occur.  Furthermore,
when examining the possible values of the size of the first positional gap, which
can range from $(0)$ through $(33)$, you have the complication that each size $(k)$
must be given a weight of $(k + 1)$.  This is because if the size of the first positional
gap is $(k)$, then $b_1$ finished in position $(k+1)$.  So, it seems to require that
some consideration be given to the probability assigned to each value of $(k)$, as
$(k)$ ranges from $(0)$ to $(33)$.

Stating the question differently, I understand that you **expect** that the size
of the first positional gap is $(3)$.  I simply don't understand the full significance of
this expectation.

As a better way of illustrating my uncertainty, consider two related problems:

- You roll a die once: what is the expected number that will occur on the die?
- You roll a die once; what is the square of the expected number that will occur on the die?

In both of the above problems, you expect a $(3.5)$ to be rolled.  In the first problem, each
of the $(6)$ possible rolls is given a weight equal to the size of the number.  So, with such
a problem, rolling a $(1)$ is given a weight of $(1)$, while rolling a $(6)$ is given a weight
of $(6)$.  These weights increase **linearly**, thus allowing one to immediately conclude,
without computation, that the answer to the first problem is $(3.5)$.

In contrast, in the 2nd problem, the roll of $(1)$ is given a weight of $(1)$, while the roll
of $(6)$ is given a weight of $(36)$, so the answer to the 2nd problem is not $(3.5)^2$.

The rebuttal argument is that in the original problem, as the size of the positional gap changes from $(k)$ to $(k+1)$,
the effect on the overall computation **is linear**.

My counter to this rebuttal is that as you change the size of the positional gap from $(k)$ to $(k+1)$,
$p(k)$, as referred to in the first approach, **is not constant**.

Therefore, I have trouble placing confidence in the validity of the 3rd approach.

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the answer of Henry. 
This is weird.  On the one hand, I (still) feel unsure of you analysis, for the same reason that I felt unsure of Mike Earnest's original answer.  That is, I had trouble determining the significance of the expectation that the size of the positional gap following the artifical person is $(3)$.

However, I just thought of a minor variation of your (Henry's) answer that I do feel confident of.

Assume that when you add the (artificial) 11th *person from B*, his position around the table is **unknown**.  So, instead of finding and removing the artificial person, you take a different approach.

Each of the $(11)$ people around the table that are from B could be the artificial person from B.  So, you run $(11)$ simulations, where with each simulation, you assume that a specific one of the $(11)$ people from B is the artificial person.  You ask yourself, with each of these $(11)$ simulations, how many people from A or C follow (clockwise) this artificial person.

Since you are running $(11)$ simulations, you will end up counting each person from A or C exactly once.  Therefore, the expected number of people from A or C that follows any given artificial person from B is $(3)$.

Actually, this becomes virtually identical to the 2nd approach by RainCatalyst.  So, it seems that I can't get away from his approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you understand the second approach, you should understand the third approach. They are the same logic, just different ways of phrasing.

While the second approach says "$x_i=1$", the third approach says "person number $i$ is in the leftmost gap," but they mean the same thing. They both argue that the probability of this happening is $1/11$, and there are $33$ other people, so on average, we get $33/11=3$. This is valid because of linearity of expectation, though the third approach does not mention this explicitly.

When you say.

> "I understand that you expect the size of the first gap to be $3$,"

then you must understand my approach. The size of first gap is three, on average. The position of $B$'s best player is one plus the size first gap. Therefore, letting $X$ be the number of people in the first gap, since
$$
E[X+1]=E[X]+1=3+1=4,
$$
we get the expected position is $4$.

I cannot tell what your complaint is with the contribution of $(k+1)$ and $p(k)$, etc has to do with my method. My approach does not even refer to $p(k)$ at all. At no point do I take a weighted average of the possible of the gap sizes  between $0$ and $33$; I avoid this entirely by using linearity of expectation. Therefore, I think your complaint is in the wrong ball park.

Comment: I don't think that the word *complaint* is appropriate here.  As I indicated, my knowledge of formal Probability theory is weak.  Therefore, I was in no way asserting that your analysis was invalid, but rather that I lacked the sophistication to verify your analysis.

Comment: Your analysis was very similar to the analysis of RainCatalyst.  However, you focused on the expectation that the average size of each positional gap is $(3)$.  My point was that while I agree with this conclusion, I don't know what to do with it.  RainCatalyst's approach was different in that he specifically computed $(3) = $ the expected value of $X = \sum_{i=1}^{33} x_i$.  This approach, was different enough from yours, that with my very limited sophistication, I was more confident in his approach than I was in yours.

Comment: @user2661923 I promise you that my approach is doing the exact same thing as RainCatalyst's, and that they are correct for the same reason. I suggest you try to rewire your thinking so that you can see that approach two and approach three are exactly the same, just reworded. I wish you the best in your continued study of probability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variety of Mike Earnest's answer.

Suppose we instead sit $18$ As, $11$ Bs (not $10$ because we have added a special extra B) and $15$ Cs around a circular table.

- Going clockwise, in the gap between any of the $11$ successive pairs of $B$s there can be $0$ to $33$ As and Cs
- By symmetry, the distributions of the numbers of As and Cs in each gap are identical.  They are not independent, but that does not matter for expectations
- The expected number of As and Cs in each gap is therefore $\frac{33}{11}=3$

Now spot and remove the special extra B and unwind the remaining people so they are in line.  The expected number of As and Cs in each gap is still $3$ as are the expected number before the first B and after the last B

So in the original problem, the expected number before the fastest $B$ is $3$, meaning the expected position of the fastest B is $4$th

Comment: See the just added Addendum to my answer.